# Run chef-client without administrator privileges

Tags: security, chef-infra

Platform:Windows Server 2012 R2

I realize what I'm asking may just have the simple flat answer of - no.

I am wondering if there is the possibility of running the chef-client on windows without administrator access. To me - it feels like a security vulnerability where if that windows machine is compromised, the compromiser has full access to that machine.

Installing MSI packages, changing IIS settings, and moving/changing permissions on folders have made this difficult however. These cookbooks make heavy use of windows chef cookbooks from the community as well as winrm.

Is there a way to run the chef-client without administrator privileges or possibly maybe a security strategy I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly run Chef without admin privs but it won't be able to do anything which requires them. So it depends on what you want to use Chef for.